# Can we consider light from the Sun during sunrise and nightfall as polarised?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science, polarization

On sunrise and nightfall light looks different, more orange or more dark. Some frequencies are filtered or light travels longer. The energy corresponding to this light is obviously lower than light from morning or noon. Is this the same effect as polarization?

Comment: If you are interested in the polarization, take a camera with a polarizing filter and take some shots of the sky. If you use the camera's raw format and  do some careful calibrations against a constant light source, you could probably do measurements with a few percent accuracy without the need for expensive equipment. The colors have nothing to do with polarization, though, they are simply scattering on air molecules and dust.

Comment: I'm very confused as to how this is being voted closed as homework. There's really nothing here *except* a pure concept.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Hi Chris, not sure if I am understanding what you mean. Could you explain further please? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to really worry about. Some users have voted to close this question as not conforming to our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange); others have voted to leave the question open. *If* is is closed, we can deal with how to improve the question.

Comment: @ChrisWhite thanks Chris. OK, now I understand: you were completely right, not homework at all. Pure conceptual question to see what others thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly dominated by Rayleigh scattering which scales as the inverse of the wavelength to the fourth power.  So shorter wavelengths are scattered more strongly.  Which is why the sky is blue and sunsets are reddish.  Indeed when the light is scattered it will appear polarized to the observer on the ground. Try looking at the blue sky through a polarizer.....